# Avoid triggering ng-change before user is finished with input

Tags: angularjs

My problem is that the user changes the `checkin` date, and then moves on to set the `checkout` date, but before he get a chance to finish setting the `checkout` date, ng-change from `checkin` fires the `vm.setDates` and interrupts him from finishing selecting dates.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="vm.checkin" id="checkinDate" ng-change="vm.setDates(vm.checkin, vm.checkout)" ng-model-options="{debounce:3000}">
<input type="date" ng-model="vm.checkout" id="checkoutDate" ng-change="vm.setDates(vm.checkin, vm.checkout)" ng-model-options="{debounce:3000}">
```

Is there a way so that ng-change does not trigger in checkin field as long as user doing stuff in checkout field? (or it has focus if thats possible?)  Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: You can add a condition in "vm.setDates" to see if both "vm.checkin" and "vm.checkout" are set and run the function only then. Something like           if (vm.checkin && vm.checkout) { <execute ng-change function here}

Comment: Wont work if the user is just there to change one of the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-focus and ng-blur to achieve this. I have created a plunker simulating this. The ng-change function simply displays the modified data, as I am not sure what the ng-change function does in your application. You can modify the if conditions in the "modifyInput()" function to whichever suits your needs. It should be achievable by using the flags on ng-focus and ng-blur.
I didn't play around much with the if conditions, as I am not sure what your specific needs are. Like the different scenarios @Varun mentioned above.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uX1IObE9NIRS9okKhwn2?p=preview

HTML:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input1" ng-change="modifyInput()" ng-focus="input1flag=true" ng-blur="input1flag=false">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input2" ng-change="modifyInput()" ng-focus="input2flag=true" ng-blur="input2flag=false">
    <p>Input 1 : {{input1_mod}}</p>
        <p>Input 2 : {{input2_mod}}</p>
<button ng-click="display()">submit</button>
<div ng-show="btnClick">
    <h4>{{input1_mod}}</h4>
        <h4>{{input2_mod}}</h4>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.btnClick=false;
  $scope.input2flag=false;
   $scope.input1flag=false;

  $scope.modifyInput = function() {
   if($scope.input1 && $scope.input2) {
$scope.input1_mod=$scope.input1+'modified';
$scope.input2_mod=$scope.input2+'modified';
}
 if($scope.input1 && !$scope.input2) {
    if ($scope.input2flag) {
    $scope.input1_mod=$scope.input1+'modified';
$scope.input2_mod=$scope.input2+'modified';
}
 }
   if($scope.input2 && !$scope.input1)
    if ($scope.input1flag) {
    $scope.input1_mod=$scope.input1+'modified';
$scope.input2_mod=$scope.input2+'modified';
}
  }

  $scope.display = function() {
     $scope.btnClick=true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Vijay this is a BRILLIANT solution!! `ng-focus="input1flag=true" ng-blur="input1flag=false"` is logical and elegant - exactly what I wanted - thank you so much!!

Comment: I just finished implementing everywhere and it works like a charm

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want query to fire only when user select the check-out date then you can use `ng-change="vm.setDates(vm.checkin, vm.checkout)` only in checkout date field.

Now issue may occur if:
 1. When user select only the check-out date and not check-in date, so in that case you can disable check-out field until check-in field is empty.
 2. When user selects both the date but now again changes the check-in date only, so in that case you can clear check-out date value if user changes check-in date

Comment: Often the user is only there to change one of the dates, and then it wont work if he only changes the checkin date.  What I need is something that looks if the user has focus to one of the date fields.

Comment: if you want action to take place in focus then go for ng-focus, it work when input is in focus state